# ReLoad URL with WebRequest VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I put online counter on my test html page and when I try to reload this page, the counter not refresh, so it seems this WebRequest not working, thanks for help, here is what I got at the moment:

```
    Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sites() As String = New String() {"TextBox1.Text"}
                Debug.WriteLine(sites.Length)
        'Stop
        For Each s As String In sites
            Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf threadimportbtcUSD)
            t.IsBackground = True
            t.Start(s)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub threadimportbtcUSD(s As Object)
        Dim asite As String = DirectCast(s, String)
        Do
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString)
            Dim postReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create(asite), Net.HttpWebRequest)

            Try
                postReq.Timeout = 5000
                postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
                Dim postresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse
                postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
                Dim risposta As String
                Dim postreqreader As New IO.StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
                risposta = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
                postreqreader.Close()
                postreqreader.Dispose()

                postresponse.Close()
                postresponse.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
                postReq.Abort()
            End Try
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL in `asite` is correct? Have you tried running HTTP debugging software like Fiddler to see if the request is being submitted?

Comment: I found this on some vb blog, and I added only few things. I need to make this work but all info I get is only to get source page or adding proxy, so I have no idea really :( so frustrationg

Comment: your Textbox contains 1 or many URLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    doSubmitHTTPRequest(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub doSubmitHTTPRequest(ByVal url As String)
    Dim webRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url & "?nocache=" & DateTime.Now.Ticks), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    webRequest.Method = "GET"
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"

    Dim responseReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()

    responseReader.Close()
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close()

    'responseData <= variable which contains the response from the server
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for code but it is not counting the viewed page and counter is still showing same hits :(

Comment: try adding `Msgbox(responseData)` at the end of the sub `doSubmitHTTPRequest` and see what the response is.

Comment: the msgbox show up and it show html code of that counter I added. What this result means?

Comment: it means it's submitting the HTTP request successfully. Something may be wrong with your counter code in your html page.

Comment: no i dont think so, it is most commonly used free counter: http://www.hitwebcounter.com/internetcountercontact.php so thx anyway I keep digging how to count the webpage url

Comment: if you're getting the html code of the page, then it submitted the request successfully...that's the only way it could show you the html. But it also may be caching it for each additional request, so if you submit it again, it just displays from cache and doesn't submit to the server. You can add a random string to the URL `url & "?nocache=" & DateTime.Now.Ticks` to break this cache.

Comment: Could you write that code where to put it please? Also when i refresh in webbrowser this counter count, but not with that httpwebrequest, maybe it will count when i download that webpage with webclient but i dont want to downlaod the page in desktop, maybe theres some way to download it and store it in some container? thanks

Comment: I added it to my original code, see above. Also, when you say _download that webpage_, that is what's happening when you refresh in your browser too...it's downloading the page, there is no difference. Loading the page or refreshing it in your browser downloads the response (in this case the HTML code) to your computer. That code is simulating the same thing that happens in your browser.

Comment: sorry  was in kitchen, OK then I saw some bytes code what download some url BUT it is only after download finish save to PC with filesave dialog, so could you help me how to not save in pc but actually only refresh it ? thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Where is the filesave dialog coming from? Is it code in your webpage? Can you update your original code with the new code?

Comment: I just said that I wil ltry to find soem code what download string uri and then not saving to PC but let it in some cookie container. thx

Comment: I need to know how the traffic bots work, so what method they use, as I am sure they dont use webbrowsers, as they have some of them up to 100 Threads so thats why i am trieng on my html web counter to get refresh that page. Hope you could help me to learn this.